# Regex that matches a string that starts with whitespace and has only digits after

Tags: regex

I need a regex that will match lines like:

```
    123
  12345
1234567
```

So I know the maximum length of a string (7) and that string can contain only digits and whitespaces at the beginning.

I have tried this one: `[ 0-9]{7}` but this one will match strings like `12 34`

Comment: What regex flavor/tool are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[ 0-9]{7}` will match 7 digits or spaces in any order and this pattern can return partial matches since it is not anchored at the start/end of the string.

You can use a lookahead restricting the length of the string, and use the *sequential* subpatterns:

```
^(?=[\s\d]{7}$)\s*\d*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eH3jM6/1)

The pattern breakdown:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=[\s\d]{7}$)` - the string will be matched only if the whole string consists of whitespaces or/and digits of whole length 7
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace symbols
- `\d*` - 0+ digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Actually what I needed was a regexp to match the followin pattern: 4digitis-7digits(with whitespace at the begining)-1digit, I addapted your answer to this: `^[\d]{4}-(?=[\s\d]{7})\s*\d*-[\d]{1}$` see: https://regex101.com/r/eB0fR3/1

Comment: The pattern you wrote can be written as `^\d{4}-(?=[\s\d]{7})\s*\d*-\d$`. The `(?=[\s\d]{7})` lookahead requires that the `\s*\d*` pattern matches at least 7 characters. See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/eB0fR3/3). I think you need [`^\d{4}-(?=[\s\d]{7}-)\s*\d*-\d$`](https://regex101.com/r/eB0fR3/4).

Comment: Yes, you are right, this is actually what I really need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

^(?=[\s\d]{7}$)\s*\d*$

looks good and will match on all example cases given in question while reducing it's FP probability near to zero.

Though, i found some cases when it might FP, specially when the string is made up of 7 spaces only or 7 newlines, or 7 new tabs, which i feel something not expected.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/eH3jM6/2

So, in order to make it perfect, let's modify it:

```
                          ^(?=[ \d]{7}$) {0,6}\d*$
```

For more reference: Check

https://www.talentcookie.com/2015/07/lets-practice-regular-expression/
https://www.talentcookie.com/2016/01/some-useful-regular-expression-terminologies/